# PHP session cannot pass session values across multiple pages

Tags: session, authentication

I need help please. I've spent the last 6 hours looking everywhere for help about using PHP session across web pages. The `$_SESSION` variable is supposed to be global, but I can only access it on the page it was declared. Like:

**Page 1 (this works):**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION ['login'] = 1;
echo $_SESSION ['login'];
```

but when I try to echo the same thing in my next web page it doesn't work.

**Page 2 (this doesn't work):**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION ['login'];
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `session_start()`? PHP >= 5.3 will return FALSE if the session fails to start. That might give you a clue.

Comment: i'm sorry please how do i check the return value?

Comment: `$x = session_start(); echo $x;` or `echo session_start();` If that gives you a `1`, your session started fine.

Comment: i got a 1 in both pages, but i still can't echo $_SESSION ['login'] from page 2 :((

Comment: are you on PHP >= 5.3? What does `echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];` give you on page2 after you've visited page1?

Comment: i thank you for your time Soumya. here's what i get: ec57fe9192b51a1f6e99d3aae79baa91

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** session is global

make sure that you are using the same domain name it may be also because of the subdomain

Comment: thanks for replying, can u please explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: He wants to say that if you create a session in `herp.example.com`, a page in `derp.example.com` won't be able to access the session data.